# Female equivalent of "creator"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

Female equivalent of "*creator*"?

Or is it unisex?

I'm a programmer and I named a variable "creatingFunction", which sounds even worse than "creatorFunction".

Comment: Just stick with creator, it's unisex.

Comment: I'll wait and see, there's an interesting discussion going on below

Comment: Why would you need a feminine equivalent in this case anyway?

Comment: @Barrie: Are you saying that "Function" is not female? I might think it is so because my native language is Spanish, and "función" is feminine

Comment: @dario_ramos nouns in English do not have gender, except, probably, when they represent a living thing. Function is neither male, not female, it is... just it.

Comment: Now I won't look at them the same way... :P

Comment: FWIW, the idiom in programming for a function that creates something is to call it a "factory."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe "creator" is unisex. In other contexts, the feminine might be "creatrix" (aviator, aviatrix), but probably not in this case.

Answer (score 9):

The OED has *creatrix*, with a first citation dated 1595, and the most recent citation dated 2001. It also has *creatress*, with equivalent citations from 1590 and 1997.

Comment: "creatress" sounds a bit better to me... How about you?

Comment: I don't trust what sounds better or not. By the way, is there a feminist angle on this?

Comment: These terms exist but are not used.

Comment: How do you mean, not used? One was used in 1997 and the other in 2001.

Comment: Let me not delete that and let it stand; on investigation, 'creatrix' -is- used, but is [negligeable in comparison to creator](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=creatrix%2C+creator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (ngram chart), but if you look at the examples for 'creatrix' they seem entirely out of the feminist literature.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't think *creatrix* is exclusively used in "feminist literature". Nature, for example, has long been personified as female, and [this usage](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MSu2w3FqepoC&pg=PA128&dq=%22creatrix%22&hl=en&ei=VaahTt7OHca38gOzhaGCBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22creatrix%22&f=false) doesn't strike me as at all odd.

Comment: In the context of the OP (a variable name) as well as any non-academic writing, it would look quite odd.

Comment: @Mitch: OP's context is ludicrous. A feminised function name? Gimmie a break!

Answer (score 4):

**[creator](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/creator)**
*noun*
**a person or thing that brings something into existence**:
*James Bond’s creator Ian Fleming

water—the creator of climate and weather*
 - (**the Creator**) used as a name for God.

ODO defines the word *creator* as **a person or thing** — not just as a person, let alone a person of specific gender. The dictionary does not define a feminine gender of *creator*, nor does it list the word ?'*creatrix*'.

Furthermore, per OP's comment above, the hypernym *function* may be feminine in Spanish, but in English it is neuter.

Comment: Yes, function is feminine in Spanish :)